# asp.net core 3.1 SignalR: pass complex object from javascript client to Hub

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to pass an object from client to hub:
On client:

```
connection.invoke('MyMethod', {
                i: 1,
                a: 25
            });
```

On hub:

```
        public async Task MyMethod(TestModel model)
        {
            // logic
        }
```

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [JsonProperty("i")]
    public double Min {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("a")]
    public double Max {get;set;}
}
```

In the MyMethod the model is not null, but the values are always 0.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The `JsonProperty` attribute is used when you're serializing the `TestModel` not binding it with json according to Newtonsoft [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm).
Did you try naming the `TestModel` fields  `i` and `a` as a test?

Comment: @HMZ you're right, renamed them and it works. How do I use simplified names then? I want to reduce the data amount per request

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your description, you should use Newtonsoft.Json in an ASP.NET Core 3.0 SignalR project, since the asp.net core doesn't use Newtonsoft.Json by default.

You should install the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson) NuGet package and then modify the startp.cs ConfigureServices method as below:

```
services.AddSignalR()
    .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol();
```

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-newtonsoftjson-in-an-aspnet-core-30-signalr-project).

Comment: what to do with client side signalR.HubConnectionBuilder?

Comment: Use this option ```.withHubProtocol(new signalR.JsonHubProtocol())```. Works with newtonsoft json protocol as well. Not sure why this isn´t in their documentation at all as far as I can tell.